# How to do post request and render response as a new page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I can send a POST request and render the response as a full page via submitting a form. How can I do that via a ajax request? That is:

```
$.ajax('test.com', {
    'method': 'POST',
    'success': function(res) {
        // open a new page, render res as a full page
        // I can't simply do window.location = "foobar" as it's a POST
    }
});
```

Or, if this is strange, what is the conventional way of doing it?

Comment: Why did you choose ajax for this task?

Comment: Submit the form using `method="POST"` instead of using script if the result page is html

Comment: The whole idea of using Ajax is to *not* render a complete new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i would go for form if you don't care about response at this point.
But if you do, you can check response and do something like this:

```
$.ajax('test.com', {
    'method': 'POST',
    'success': function(res) {
        if ( res.code == 200 )
            document.location = 'page1.htm';
        else
            alert('error!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't do this as it's not a location. It will be a page response generated on-the-fly based on my POST data

Comment: So you should check out first answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to open result of your form processing in new page you don't need ajaxa and you can just use target property of form like

```
<form action="http://test.com/" method="post" target="_blank">
Your inputs, etc.
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using form?

Comment: Why you want to avoid form? User is entering data somewehere anyway. If you really don't need it, I can just create form on the fly, send and never show to user. That's how ajax file uploads working without File API.

Comment: I just feel it's convoluted and there should be a more straightforward way... But anyways, thanks!